# Encrypt communication between Qt application and Python service

Tags: python, qt, python-2.7, encryption, qt5

I have a cross-platform application in Qt5 and QML that works with Python-2.7 service through HTTP using JSON format.

I need the service to be used by my software only and no one else could use it.

The data passed to webservice and from webserivce should be encrypted.

Is it possible to implement such secure encrypted communication between Qt5 cross-platform application and Python service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use SSL in Qt applications: [Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) Classes](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtnetwork/ssl.html)